# Renaming a field on a Django queryset with group by

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm counting the users by month that have been registered this year.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models import F

return Response(User.objects
    .filter(date_joined__year=timezone.now().year)
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date_joined'))
    .values('month')
    .annotate(qtd=Count('id'))
    .values('date_joined__month', 'qtd')
```

The result of this queryset it's been returned as:

```
[{"date_joined__month": 1,"qtd": 5},{"date_joined__month": 2,"qtd": 35}]
```

I want to change the name of the field "*date_joined__month*" to "*month_id*" and keep the counting and group by logic.

I already tried to add the following approaches, but they both returned the full date format instead return only the month id: *"month_id": "2021-01-07T15:26:53.080136Z"*

```
.annotate(month_id=F('date_joined__month'))
.values('qtd', 'month_id'))

or

.values('qtd', month_id=F('date_joined__month')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the name of your annotation, so:

```
return Response(User.objects.filter(
    date_joined__year=timezone.now().year
).values(
    month_id=TruncMonth('date_joined')
).annotate(qtd=Count('id')).order_by('month_id')
```

or if you want to extract the `Month` itself, you can work with [**`ExtractMonth`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractMonth)

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth

return Response(User.objects.filter(
    date_joined__year=timezone.now().year
).values(
    month_id=ExtractMonth('date_joined')
).annotate(qtd=Count('id')).order_by('month_id')
```

Comment: This solution returns the field with the correct name, but isn't return only the month id, it returns a full timezone/date format as: { "month_id": "2021-01-01T00:00:00-03:00" }

Comment: @PatrickFreitas: ah, then you are probably looking for `ExtractMonth`, not `TruncMonth`.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you!